# a Non-linear Mass-spring system with different force and vibration frequency?

Tags: resonance, vibrations, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

I got a classic mass-spring system with zero damp ratio, having weird behaviour.

The input frequency of external force is twice that of the output displacement results. While linear systems' input & output frequency should be the same. My case should be a non-linear vibration.

In other words, $f_{vibration}=f_n=1/2\pi*\sqrt{k/m}$ but the unexplainable is that $f_{external force}=2f_n$.

[image: FFT]

In addition, the system is driven by moving fluid around the object with mass. There is some fluid-structure interaction taking place. The resonance actually occurred at the fluid natural frequency, yet this is at 1 time of structural natural frequency.

Have you encountered any non-linear system with such feature?

More fundamentally, is it possible for the external force to affect the linearity of a mass-spring-undamped system?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is the output frequency the natural frequency of the spring-mass system?

Comment: @Farcher Yes, exactly the structural natural frequency.  $f_{vibration}=f_n=1/2\pi*sqrt{k/m}$ but the unexplainable is that $f_{external force}=2f_n$

Comment: Your driver most probably is exciting the spring-mass system at its resonant frequency which is producing large oscillations because the system is undamped. The 2n oscillations are not seen because they are marked by the n oscillations. With little damping your spring-mass system will have a very high Q-value. How are you driving the spring-mass system?

Comment: @Farcher You said "marked" do you mean "hidden" by the fn oscillation? I attached an FFT result, and I think the vibration frequency at $1*f_n$ is much more dominant than that at $2*f_n$? The system is driven by disturbed fluid around the object with mass. The resonance actually occurred at the fluid natural frequency, yet this is at 1 time of structural natural frequency.

Comment: I meant "masked" but the spell checker thought otherwise.

Comment: I guess it is not masked according to FFT in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing is most likely a *subharmonic* oscillation, presumably imposed by some *nonlinear* characteristic of your system. I would expect the fluid. The paper [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110015498.pdf) explains the mechanisms of subharmonic oscillations in nonlinear systems and offers at least one example where the subharmonic occurs at half the drive frequency.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the clue! Will check that through!

Answer (score 0):

The external force is able to influence the linearity of the vibrational systems, as $F(t)$ can be $F(\dot{x},t)$ etc.

More materials found online, I am still trying to figure out:

"Vibrations of a Forced Self-excited System with Time lag" by Yutaka 1983

Parametric oscillator:
Michael Faraday (1831) was the first to notice oscillations of one frequency being excited by forces of double the frequency, in the crispations (ruffled surface waves) observed in a wine glass excited to "sing".